# sql command to flatten 2 tables with many to many relation

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables with many to many relation. Consider the below use case

**Patients**

```
id | Name
---+------------------
1    jack
2    sara
3    patrick
```

**Diseases**

```
id | Disease
---+-----------------
1    Diabetes
2    Cancer
3    Epilepsy
```

Each patient can have several  diseases.The junction table is:

**PatientDisease**

```
Patient_id | Disease_id
-----------+--------------
1                1
1                3
2                2
```

I want to list the diseases for every patient.

**Attempts**

The below query creates the semi-correct result for patient who have one or more disease:

```
SELECT 
    Patients.Name,  
    Diseases = STUFF((SELECT ',' + dbo.Diseases.Name 
                      FROM dbo.Diseases 
                      FOR  XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.Patients
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.PatientDiseases ON PatientDiseases.Patient_Id = Patients.Id
JOIN 
    dbo.Diseases ON Diseases.Id = PatientDiseases.Disease_Id
```

How can I write a query that produces an output like this?

```
name    | diseases
--------+-------------------
jack    | diabetes, Epilepsy
sara    | cancer
patrick | NULL
```

Comment: That query you've provided can't run, it doesn't have a `FROM`.

Comment: You are right. fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you should be doing is this:

```
SELECT P.[Name],
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + D.Disease
              FROM dbo.PatientDisease PD
                   JOIN dbo.Diseases D ON PD.Disease_id = D.id
              WHERE PD.Patient_id = P.id
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS Diseases
FROM dbo.Patients P;
```

If you're using SQL Server 2017, you can use `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT P.[Name],
       STRING_AGG(D.Disease,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.Disease) AS Diseases
FROM dbo.Patients P
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PatientDisease PD ON P.id = PD.Patient_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Diseases D ON PD.Disease_id = D.id
GROUP BY P.[Name];
```